# Homomorphism from $(GL(3, \mathbb{R}), .)$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{>0}, .)$ such that $\Phi(2I_3)=8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I need to find a Homomorphism from $(GL(3, \mathbb{R}), .)$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{>0}, .)$ such that $\Phi(2I_3)=8$.

I know that $\Phi(A)=|det(A)|$ would be a homomorphism from $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, but I don't see how to modify this to be a homomorphism that satisfies the second condition.

Comment: Can you compute $det(2I_3)$ ?

Comment: @Max Yes, it is $4$, so it doesn't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Ohh god, I see it now! It's time for me to sleep. Sorry!

Comment: In case it is isn't obvious, $|det(2I_3)|=2\times 2 \times 2 = 8$ so $|det(A)|$ works just fine. I need to get some sleep, thanks Max